# Manually but effectivly blur or pixelate area / object from hunderts of similar photos

Tags: ubuntu, photography, image-editor

I am looking for a software to similar areas of lots of similar 360 photos. So EXIF information should be preserved.

I am having something in mind where I select the area to be blurred, switch quickly to the next photo, the same area is preselected and I can modifiy the area or move on to the next photo.

Is there such a software for Ubuntu available?

I know about

- Imagmagick - which can do batch processing, but only automatically - but I have to be able to select the area on each image, so this is not working
- Shotwell - which lets me quickly skip through photos an to basic editing, but it allows only cropping, no pixelating / bluring
- Gimp - where I can do such stuff, but it is a big hassle to load, save close all the pictures

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a recent version of gimp you could write, (or find someone to write), a gimp python plugin that would allow you to select the area of interest on one of the photos and when invoked would apply your change to the selected area, save the file (export) and close it and load the next file that matches a wildcard, from a known/the same directory, *(glob.glob)*, or even traverses a set of sub-directories, *(os.walk)*, loading each in turn, prompting you to any of skip, apply, change selection.

- The, *currently incomplete*, documentation on the python plugin is [here](https://www.gimp.org/docs/python/index.html).
- Some useful examples are [here](http://gimpbook.com/scripting/).
- One tutorial for Linux is [here](http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/tutorials/6720/1).
- A really good set of video & text tutorials can be found [here](https://jacksonbates.wordpress.com/python-fu-gimp-scripting-tutorial-pages/).